# Building libosmocore on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, c, gnu-make

I've configured the source with these arguments:

```
autoreconf -fi
./configure --disable-pcsc --disable-libmnl --disable-gb
```

And it went just well, and then after running 'make' command and in middle of building I get these errors:

```
gmake[2]: Entering directory '/usr/home/test_usr/libosmocore-1.5.2/utils'
  CCLD     osmo-arfcn
ld: error: ../src/.libs/libosmocore.so: undefined reference to osmo_timerfd_disable [--no-allow-shlib-undefined]
ld: error: ../src/.libs/libosmocore.so: undefined reference to osmo_timerfd_schedule [--no-allow-shlib-undefined]
ld: error: ../src/.libs/libosmocore.so: undefined reference to osmo_timerfd_setup [--no-allow-shlib-undefined]
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:545: osmo-arfcn] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/home/test_usr/libosmocore-1.5.2/utils'
gmake[1]: *** [Makefile:708: all-recursive] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/home/test_usr/libosmocore-1.5.2'
gmake: *** [Makefile:487: all] Error 2
```

Has anybody faced this issue ? How can i resolve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you investigate the output from `configure` and check if the header `sys/timerfd.h` is available and usable on FreeBSD? According to the sources, these three functions (undefined reference) requires this header.

Comment: Thank you @krjdev , You're correct. There are dependencies on timerfd_* functions which is not supported on FreeBSD. Thank you.